# Articolo determinativo con il possessivo

Tags: pronouns, articles

Sono uno studente principiante di italiano. (La mia prima lingua è l'inglese.) Ho una domanda sull'utilizzo di articoli determinativi con il possessivo. C'è una differenza tra dire:

> Il pane è mio

e

> Il pane è il mio

Sono entrambi corretti? Hanno significati diversi?

Mi dispiace se la mia domanda è scritta male. Ho usato "Google translate" per scrivere. Grazie per qualsiasi aiuto.

Comment: La seconda forma può anche indicare che il pane è di tua produzione (lo hai impastato e cotto in forno).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say both, even if I'd say the former is usually the normally used form. The latter can be used with proper voice intonation in order to clearly state that **the bread is yours**.

Another little difference is that when you say 
***Il pane è mio*** (the bread is mine)
you claim the possession of the bread and the phrase is complete.

If you say ***il pane è il mio***, the person you're talking to, according to the tone of your voice, may also expect some other words, like:

***Il pane è il mio cibo preferito*** (bread is my favorite food)

Comment: Oh, it's okay to speak English on this site? Good to know!

Comment: If you don't feel confident with Italian it's perfectly welcome if you have questions about our marvelous language. But I dare say your question was written in a very good Italian and can be easily understood.

Comment: I agree with the answer: the second sentence has a more assertive/imperative tone.

Comment: In fact, I suspect he improved on what Google spewed.  I've never seen GT do that well.

Comment: I did polish what I got from Google, a little. It didn't translate "definite article" correctly, for example.